# iPhone Media Query

Tags: css

I am new to media queries.  Does anyone know why these iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 media queries conflict with one another.  I am adding queries incorrectly? I plan to add Landscape queries along with other screen sizes.

```
 /********* IPHONE 6 PORTRAIT**********/
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 375px) 
 and (max-device-width : 667px) 
 and (orientation : portrait) { 
 .topten {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1115px;
    float: left;
 }
 .submenu {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
 }
 .toptenItem {
    width: 50%;
    height: 16.683%;
 }
 .imageDIV {
    height: 45%;
 }
 .imageDIV img {
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 100%;
 }
.mealTitlePrice {
    height: 55%;
    padding-left: 10px;
 }
 .mealTitle {
    height: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
 }
 .mealTitle h1 {
    font-size: .55em;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
.mealPrice {
    margin-top: px;
}
.mealPrice h4 {
    padding-top: 2px;
}
}

/********* IPHONE 5 PORTRAIT**********/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
 .topten {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1115px;
    float: left;
}
.toptenItem {
    width: 50%;
    height: 16.683%;
}
}
```

Comment: If I modify something on the iPhone 6 query the iPhone 5 content is also modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing all "common" css at the top, outside of the media queries. Then change what you need as the screen width/height changes. This gives you a base to work with.

For example:

```
/********* BASE CSS **********/
 .toptenItem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }

/********* IPHONE 6 PORTRAIT**********/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
 .toptenItem {
    width: 50%;
    height: 16.683%;
 }
}

/********* IPHONE 5 PORTRAIT**********/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
 .toptenItem {
    width: 70%;
    height: 18%;
 }
}
```

Also, I notice the css in the media queries are exactly the same. Normally this isn't the case as you're trying to change the css to something specific for that media query. I changed them in my example above to avoid confusion.